# user -> guacamole <- vnc server

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, vnc-server, guacamole

how would you set up a server running guacamole to listen for a reverse vnc connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way, not using guacamole, by running a vnc repeater (i used uvnc repeater), which will listen for connection from the vnc servers and viewers, and connect the servers and viewers that use the same id

http://www.wisdomsoftware.gr/en/ultravnc-repeater-en/5-how-to-install-ultravnc-repeater-for-linux-debian-a-centos