# Unable to use Guacamole Reverse VNC connection

Tags: vnc, guacamole

I am using **Guacamole v0.9.9** and want to connect to my **Win 10 laptop** which is behind a **NAT** of my ISP.

I figured I might have to use **Reverse VNC** for this. The instructions are given here:
https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#vnc-reverse-connections

But I am using MYSQL Auth as described here:
https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/doc/0.9.0/gug/mysql-auth.html

The problem is that I am not able to see any options for Reverse Connection in VNC settings and there is no XML file to put the parameters in.

[image]

Also there is no instruction what to do after that. In a conventional VNC connection you would run the client in the destination and run the server in listen/reverse mode after giving destination ip. In this case there is no client running. So I am clueless what to do next.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Alternately you could [**use a vnc repeater** as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046562/319204).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you'll need to do in order to setup the `reverse-connect` functionality:

So in a typical authorization scenario you have something like this in the **[`user-mapping.xml`](https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/doc/0.8.3/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#basic-auth)** with the necessary information for the reverse-connect:

```
<authorize username="user" password="password">
    <connection name="reverse">
        <protocol>vnc</protocol>
        <param name="hostname">localhost</param>
        <param name="port">9999</param>
        <param name="reverse-connect">true</param>
        <param name="listen-timeout">30000</param>
        <param name="autoretry">true</param>
    </connection>
</authorize>
```

Since you are doing this through MySQL it's the same principle:

**Connections and parameters**

> Each connection has an entry in the guacamole_connection table, with a
>   one-to-many relationship to parameters, stored as name/value pairs in
>   the guacamole_connection_parameter table.
>
> The guacamole_connection table is simply a pairing of a unique and
>   descriptive name with the protocol to be used for the connection. Adding a connection and corresponding parameters is relatively easy compared to adding a user as there is no salt to generate nor password to hash:

```
-- Create connection
INSERT INTO guacamole_connection (connection_name, protocol) VALUES ('reverse', 'vnc');
SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

-- Add parameters
INSERT INTO guacamole_connection_parameter VALUES (@id, 'hostname', 'localhost');
INSERT INTO guacamole_connection_parameter VALUES (@id, 'port', '9999');
INSERT INTO guacamole_connection_parameter VALUES (@id, 'reverse-connect', 'true');
...
```

**Connecting**:

Open the connection within Guacamole, then connect to the port on the Guacamole Server with the VNC client (eg. `:9999` as shown in the example above). If you don't open the connection within Guacamole first, `guacd` won't be listening on the given port.

If you cannot establish a connection after setting up the `user-mapping.xml` or MySQL authorization that includes the reverse-connect parameter, it's suggested to install the latest version of **[`libvncserver`](https://github.com/LibVNC/libvncserver/releases)**, which has [`ENABLED_VNC_LISTEN`](https://apache.googlesource.com/incubator-guacamole-server/+/0.9.1/configure.ac#265) defined. You should notice when executing Guacamole's `./configure` a warning if it's not defined:

```
--------------------------------------------
 No listening support found in libvncclient.
 Support for listen-mode connections will not be built.
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I tried this give the correct information in user-mappind.xml and connect from windows pc using command  `.\tvnserver.exe -controlservice -connect 192.168.0.107:8000` using tightvnc server. But getting error Failed to connect tightvnc server.

Answer (score 1):

To save yourself some hassle you could use a vnc repeater, it will listen for connection from the vnc servers and viewers, and connect the servers and viewers that use the same id

You can get one from [here](http://www.wisdomsoftware.gr/download/uvncrep017-ws.tar.gz)

## Get build packages

## For Debian use

```
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` libx11-6 libx11-dev x-window-system-core x-window-system xspecs libxtst6 psmisc build-essential
```

## For CentOS use:

```
yum install linux-headers-`uname -r` libx11-6 libx11-dev x-window-system-core x-window-system xspecs libxtst6 psmisc build-essential
```

## Get source into /usr/local/src

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://www.wisdomsoftware.gr/download/uvncrep017-ws.tar.gz
```

## Unzip source file

```
gunzip uvncrep017-ws.tar.gz
tar -xvf uvncrep017-ws.tar
```

## Install startup script

```
cd uvncrep017-ws
make; make install;
```

## Add a user for the service

```
useradd uvncrep
```

## Edit /etc/uvnc/uvncrepeater.ini according to your needs.

## Check the following parameters:

```
viewerport = 5901
maxsessions = 10
runasuser = uvncrep
logginglevel = 2
srvListAllow1 = 192.168.0.0 ;Allow network 192.168.x.x
srvListDeny0 = 127.0.0.1 ;Deny loopback
requirelistedserver=1
```

## Start the service

```
/etc/init.d/uvncrepeater start
```

Original link: [here](http://www.wisdomsoftware.gr/en/ultravnc-repeater-en/5-how-to-install-ultravnc-repeater-for-linux-debian-a-centos)

Discussion on a board about this: [here](http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?p=80701)